# Won't boot unless I manually select drive

Tags: bios

I freshly installed Ubuntu on an M.2 drive using zfs.  The bios picks this up as the one and only boot option.  And yet, when I reboot, everything just goes blank and I have to hard reset.  I can still get it to boot by manually going into the bios, going into the boot list, and double clicking on the one option to boot to it.

```
$ efibootmgr 
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000
Boot0000* ubuntu
```

The above seems perfectly correct to me.  Manually clicking that one option shouldn't be any different from letting it boot on its own, and yet only manually clicking it works.

If I enable CSM I get two options (Both pointing to the same M2 SSD), but I've tried making either of them first and still no luck. And get this (with verbose on): (x'd out some detail)

```
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,0001
Boot0001* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)..GO..NO........q.S.a.m.s.u.n.g. .S.S.D. .9.8.0. .P.R.O. .1.T.B....................A...........................%8.!..|.....4..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.S.5.G.X.N.X.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x........BO
Boot0002* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,1872fa52-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-7eba6aa2xxxx,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)..BO
```

If I set it to "Legacy only", then something different happens where instead of going blank it presents some text that says I can't boot from that device.  I also tried disabling fast boot.

To be clear, this appears to be a bios issue and not a grub issue since, as far as I can tell, it never makes it to grub.

Answer (score 1):

Resetting my bios fixed this issue.  The setting that caused this problem was enabling XMP.